# There are no probes in Mpg even it is enabled

Tags: ibm-datapower

I have 2 mpgs. request from soapui reaches 1st mpg after processing it goes to 2nd mpg and reaches wsp then iib (1st mpg -> 2nd mpg -> wsp -> iib). Even though probes are enabled for both the mpgs I can see the probes only for 1st and there is no probes written for 2nd. i have cross checked the outbound-url of 1st and it is actually pointing to 2nd mpg.

If i send a request for 2nd mpg alone the probes are working. Please suggest a fix or opinion.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Mhm, sounds interesting.
You are not seeing the transaction in MPGW2 Probe if it comes through MPGW1, right (not only not seeing the payload)?
What do debug logs tell you when you run through the full chain, is request flowing from MPGW1 through MPGW2 as you see per params in Probe of MPGW1? If this remains inconclusive consider to also study PCAPs that go through the chain.
Just for best practices, ensure persistent connections are disabled between MPGW1 and MPGW2 (I don't think that should impact Probe).
What kind of actions do your MPGWs' processing rules apply?
Are you handling XML or JSON or what other payload? Have you set MPGW2 processing rule for binary processing if payload is non-XML?
Well, you see, so many questions, maybe worth to raise a support ticket with IBM for most effective investigation?

Comment: currently handling XML. mpgw1 is for transforming the request and mpgw2 is for WSRR communication from where im getting the outbound-url. so the request is received by the iib team which means the wsrr connection is happening and the problem is no probes.  is there any possibility that cache is giving the backend url? and then there is no logs in mpgw1 also